# Issue with GetLocalResource object

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I am trying to access my local resources file in my code-behind. I did some googling since I was unsure of how to do it and found this:

```
oContent.Text = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("NonSupport").ToString();
```

However, I get an error saying that it needs at least two parameters: `VirtualPath` and `ResourceKey`. There is a third, `CultureInfo` but that one is optional. When I put this in as my virtual path:

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("App_LocalResources/ExpandableListView.aspx.resx", "NonSupport").ToString();
```

I get the following compiler error message:

> The relative virtual path 'App_LocalResources/ExpandableListView.aspx.resx' is not allowed here.

I must be doing something wrong with this since my searches (and some posts I found on here) say all I need to do is call the resource key.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you put a resource file with the name `(your aspx web page).aspx.resx` into a `App_LocalResource` folder underneath the path where your ASPX page lives??

Furthermore, just simply call the `GetLocalResourceObject` method on your current page:

```
oContent.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("NonSupport").ToString();
```

No need to use HttpContext for that - the method is defined on the `Page` class.

Marc

Comment: Yes. I added an asp.net folder (App_LocalResources) into the directory where this aspx file resides.

Comment: OK - did you use the Visual Studio "Add ASP.NET folder" method?

Comment: Yep. Right clicked on the parent folder, selected "Add ASP.NET folder..." then selected the local resource one

Comment: Thanks. The underlying problem was my class was declared static (dunno why it was there, maybe ReSharper added it) and the GetLocalResourceObject cannot be accessed inside of a static context.

Comment: OK, glad you found the culprit and a solution for it!